# How does multitail buffer its output?

Tags: python, linux, redhat

This may not be the best wording for the question. I am trying to see 2 files at once on my screen.
I run:

```
multitail ~/path/to/somefile.err ~/path/to/somefile.out
```

I have a python script with the following lines:

```
sys.stdout = open('~/path/to/somefile.out', 'a')
sys.stderr = open('~/path/to/somefile.err', 'a')
```

My multitail command seems to only output my .out file, regardless of which order I put the files in the command.

I verified that my script is indeed writing to the files. What is also interesting, was that when I run the following command:

```
echo "text" >> ~/path/to/somefile.err
```

All of a sudden I see all the output from the .err file in the multitail screen (including that which didn't show up before)!

What is going on here that I can not see?

P.S. this is my first time using multitail so maybe I overlooked something simple. If it means anything, I am using CentOS 7.

Comment: the stderr (.err) is probably being buffered and after enough info has been buffered then it will all appear. Look for `unbuffer` on your machine, and if exists, you can `unbuffer` individual output cmds (not sure what you do in `python`.). You can probably do `unbuffer python3 mypython.py`. In the GNU coreutils, there is also `stdbuf` which does the same thing, but may need to be called differently. Check `man stdbuf`.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass either `buffering=0` (for unbuffered) or `buffering=1` (for line-buffered - probably what you want) in your call to `open`.

The default is `buffering=-1`, which is equivalent to something like `buffering=512` with a value depending on the system, so nothing will be written to the file until 512 (or whatever) bytes are written.

---

Alternatively, you could leave `buffering` set to its default value, and call `.flush()` every time you want the data to appear in the file.

---

When you use `>>` in the shell, that will close the file when the command exits, and closing implies a flush. (You can defer the close by using `exec >> file.txt`)